# Reposistioning Icons in Windows Store apps

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I'm using a set of icons inside my Windows Store App for some functionality, I want to code for rearranging  according to user wish like how we see in Windows 8 Start Screen. I want guidance and some resources for it, Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: It is difficult to understand what you mean, but it appears that you have a collection of pictures that you want to be able to drag and drop into specific positions? If this is the case, you should look into GridView, as it has Drag and Drop capability, including reordering. You can check out the Windows 8 app samples [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Windows-8-Modern-Style-App-Samples). I would look at the two XAML ListView and Gridview samples: essentials and customizing interactivity. If you have any further questions after that research, feel free to return afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Check out JQuery's GridView. Like Nate said. There are apps in the store that demonstrates the gridview. See CodeShow app. It's made from Javascript though.